# Model class from another path throws error calling module in NativeScript

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I had a web application which worked perfectly and then migrated it with NativeScript into a mobile application.
I have a model file in **`src/app/model`**, where I have inside some class model exported like this:

```
export class User {

  username: string;
  password: string;

}
```

I am trying to import that class model to a service class. My service class path is ***src/app/auto-generated/service***. When I am importing it, the app does not work. But when I am creating the same class model in the ***src/app/auto-generated*** and then import it to my service class, it works. Why it going on with the paths? How can I fix it?

How my file is when the error comes:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { User } from 'app/model/User';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class UserLoginService {
  user: User = new User();

  constructor() {}

  login(name: string, password: string, imTid: string): Observable<UiInfo> {
    console.log(name);
    return ;
  }

}
```

And the error:

> System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application
>   com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
>   System.err: System.err: Error calling module function System.err:
>   System.err: Cannot compile
>   /data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/bundle.js System.err:
>   System.err: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! System.err: File:
>   "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/bundle.js,
>   line: 292, column: 24 System.err: System.err: StackTrace: System.err: 
>   Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266 System.err:
>   Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1 System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'',
>   line: 1, column: 266 System.err: System.err: System.err: SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token ! System.err: File: ", line: 1, column: 265
>   System.err: System.err: StackTrace: System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266 System.err:
>   Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1 System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'',
>   line: 1, column: 266 System.err: System.err: System.err: SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token ! System.err: File: ", line: 1, column: 265
>   System.err: System.err: StackTrace: System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266 System.err:
>   Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1 System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'',
>   line: 1, column: 266 System.err: System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5876)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) System.err:
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) System.err: 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: System.err:
>   System.err: Error calling module function System.err: System.err:
>   Cannot compile
>   /data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/bundle.js System.err:
>   System.err: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! System.err: File:
>   "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/bundle.js,
>   line: 292, column: 24 System.err: System.err: StackTrace: System.err: 
>   Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266 System.err:
>   Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1 System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'',
>   line: 1, column: 266 System.err: System.err: System.err: SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token ! System.err: File: ", line: 1, column: 265
>   System.err: System.err: StackTrace: System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266 System.err:
>   Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1 System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'',
>   line: 1, column: 266 System.err: System.err: System.err: SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token ! System.err: File: ", line: 1, column: 265
>   System.err: System.err: StackTrace: System.err:     Frame:
>   function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266 System.err:
>   Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1 System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'',
>   line: 1, column: 266 System.err: System.err:     at
>   com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method) System.err:     at
>   com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:624) System.err:     at
>   com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:616) System.err:     at
>   com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1154)
>   System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5871)
>   System.err:     ... 8 more Successfully synced application
>   org.nativescript.ngsample on device emulator-5554.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2015"
  }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by it doesn't work? What error is shown exactly? Can you show your import statements too.

Comment: @Manoj posted it. Thanks!!

Comment: Can you also show your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @Manoj done!! Thanks

Comment: Try adding `"baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": [
                "./src/*"
            ]}` to your tsconfig.json and use `import { User } from '~/app/model/User';`

Comment: @Manoj the same error again :(

Comment: Can you share a sample project on Github?

Comment: @Manoj Unfortunately not since my client does not allow me. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code:-

```
  import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
  import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
  import { User } from 'app/model/User';

  @Injectable({
   providedIn: "root"
  })
  export class UserLoginService {
  public user: User;

  constructor() {
    this.user = new User();
  }

   login(name: string, password: string, imTid: string): Observable<UiInfo> {
    console.log(name);
    return ;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. The solution was just to change the path to:

```
import { User} from "../../../../model/User";
```