# TypeScript classes cannot be resolved from a Component's file in NativeScript

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular, tsconfig

I am facing a big issue. I already posted a similar question but I did not receive any answer.

I migrated a web application developed with Angular version 7 to a NativeScript mobile application.

The web application had already some TypeScript classes in the path ***src/app/model***.

Example of User.ts in path ***src/app/model/User.ts***:

```
export class User {

  username: string;
  password: string;

}
```

I have a component in the path ***src/app/shared-modules/navigation/create-user/first-step/first-step.component.tns.ts***:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { User } from 'app/model/User';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class UserLoginService {
  user: User = new User();

  constructor() {}

}
```

I am trying to import my **User.ts** file in the **first-step.component.tns.ts**, but it throws the error:

> An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application
>   com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
>
> Error calling module function
>
> Cannot compile
>   /data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/bundle.js
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! File:
>   "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/bundle.js,
>   line: 465, column: 28
>
> StackTrace:   Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
>     Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1,
>   column: 266
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! File: ", line: 1, column: 265
>
> StackTrace:   Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
>     Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1,
>   column: 266
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! File: ", line: 1, column: 265
>
> StackTrace:   Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
>     Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1,
>   column: 266
>
> at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5876)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
>
> Error calling module function
>
> Cannot compile
>   /data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/bundle.js
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! File:
>   "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/bundle.js,
>   line: 465, column: 28
>
> StackTrace:   Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
>     Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1,
>   column: 266
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! File: ", line: 1, column: 265
>
> StackTrace:   Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
>     Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1,
>   column: 266
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ! File: ", line: 1, column: 265
>
> StackTrace:   Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
>     Frame: function:'',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/starter.js',
>   line: 3, column: 1    Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1,
>   column: 266
>
> at com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)     at
>   com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:624)   at
>   com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:616)     at
>   com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:21)
>     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1154)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5871)
>     ... 8 more

My **tsconfig.tns.json** file:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": [
                "./*"
            ],
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
                "./node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting the error when you import User.ts? try to create User.ts in same folder then import. That will help you to find if the problem is with file or path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Model class from another path throws error calling module in NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888612/model-class-from-another-path-throws-error-calling-module-in-nativescript)

Comment: @Narendra yes the post was made again by me because no one gave me a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to this for example declare your model class in constructor also like:-

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { User } from 'app/model/User';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: "root"
})
export class UserLoginService {
    public user: User;

    constructor() {
      this.user = new User();
    }
}
```